# JSON with "(" ")" brackets istead of "[" "]"

Tags: ios, json, cocoa-touch

in .m:

```
   @implementation ViewController
    {
    NSDictionary *_json;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=Si%C3%B3fok&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=mykey"];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError *error;
    _json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    NSDictionary* fullDictFromjson = _json[@"data"];

    NSLog(@"%@",fullDictFromjson);

    NSDictionary* currentCondition = fullDictFromjson[@"current_condition"];

    NSLog(@"%@",currentCondition);
```

After this I got this in Console ( currentCondition ):

```
2013-04-18 22:18:16.758 weather[18111:c07] (
        {
        cloudcover = 0;
        humidity = 74;
        "observation_time" = "08:18 PM";
        precipMM = "0.0";
        pressure = 1019;
        "temp_C" = 11;
        "temp_F" = 51;
        visibility = 10;
        weatherCode = 113;
        weatherDesc =         (
                        {
                value = Clear;
            }
        );
        weatherIconUrl =         (
                        {
                value = "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0008_clear_sky_night.png";
            }
        );
        winddir16Point = S;
        winddirDegree = 170;
        windspeedKmph = 5;
        windspeedMiles = 3;
    }
)
```

And I can t work with this.

If I open this url in safari:

"current_condition": [ {"cloudcover": "0",  ..... So there is "[" not  "("

So my json is wrong, in xcode

What should I do?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your json. The "url in safari" is a text representation of the actual json. The log result is a text representation of an NSDictionary in an NSArray. Both are perfectly correct.

Comment: Yes now I understand :)  But why i got -2 for a question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are seeing in your log output is just the formatting of a collection of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` objects, not the actual JSON itself.  Where there's a `[` in the source JSON and a `(` in your log statements, you have an array; where there's a `{` you have a dictionary.

So you need to extract the dictionary from the single-element array before you can use it:

```
NSDictionary* currentCondition = fullDictFromjson[@"current_condition"][0];
```

Comment: and now I understand it :)