# Can't Extract Array from JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsjsonserialization

I'm trying to parse the response from my server which is in the JSON format.

This is the first part of my code:

```
// (responseBody is of type NSData)
guard let dictionary = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseBody!, options: [.MutableContainers]) else{
    fatalError("JSON Root Dictionary Not Found")
}

print("Dictionary: \(dictionary)")
```

...and the log rightly gives:

```
Dictionary: {
    count = 1;
    date = "2015-12-22T13:16:17.727";
    items =     (
                {
            attribute1 = null;
            attribute2 = null;
            attribute3 = null;
            date = "2015-12-22T17:30:52.764";
            size = 9175;
            version = 19;
        }
    );
}
```

*(irrelevant fields omitted, relevant field names and values changed for confidentiality)*

...so the value for the key `items` seems to be an object that conforms to "an array of dictionaries, each with keys of type `String` and values of type `Any`".

Next, on to obtain the `items` array:

```
guard let count = dictionary["count"] as? Int else {
    fatalError("Item Count Not Found")
}

guard count > 0 else {
    fatalError("Item Count Is Zero")
}

guard let items = dictionary["items"]! else{
    fatalError("Items Array Not Found")
}

if items is Array<Any> { 
    // THIS TEST FAILS (SHOULD PASS?)
    print("Items is an array")
}
else if items is Dictionary<String, Any> {
    // THIS TEST FAILS, TOO (JUST OUT OF DESPERATION...)
    print("Items is a dictionary")
}
else{
    // ...SO THIS CODE RUNS.
    print("Really? \(items)")
}
```

However -as the comments in the code above explain- I am not able to cast it to an array and instead the last `print()` call is executed (`print("Really? \(items)")`), giving:

```
Really? (
        {
        attribute1 = null;
        attribute2 = null;
        attribute3 = null;
        date = "2015-12-22T17:30:52.764";
        size = 9175;
        version = 19;
    }
)
```

...so, **What is the type of `items` and how can I obtain my array?**

Perhaps I am missing something about Swift's collection types?

---

**NOTE:** At first I was suspisious of the array elements being enclosed in round brackets (`()`) instead of square ones (`[]`). However, the console output of dictionaries and arrays seems to follow this format, as explained in [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092546/json-with-brackets-istead-of).

---

**UPDATE:** Based on the hints given by @Paulw11 in comments below, I got around the problem by using this code:

```
guard let items = dictionary["items"]! as? NSMutableArray else{
    fatalError("Items Array Not Found")
}

for element in documents {               // I wish I could combine these                 
    let item = element as! NSDictionary  // two lines into one (enumeration and cast)

    print("Item: \(item)")
}
```

...however, it still isn't clear to me how to implement a pure-Swift solution that does not rely on Foundation classes.

---

**UPDATE 2:** I'm trying to cast the `NSMutableArray` to a native Swift array with the code below:

```
if var nativeItems = items as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

}
```

But this gives me:

> WARNING: Cast from 'NSMutableArray' to unrelated type '[[String :
>   AnyObject]]' always fails

at the location of the `if` block, and (wait for it):

> ERROR: Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error
>   is not handled.

...at AppDelegate.swift (CoreData boilerplate), the exact same symptom [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823072/swift-2-0-migration-errors).

**The CoreData code was compiling until now.** The error disappears if I comment out the `if var nativeItems = items...` cast. Changing variable names has no effect. Definitely. Voodoo.

Fortunately, I could get around it by expanding the `catch` clause  in the boilerplate's `lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {...` part from this:

```
catch let error as NSError {
        // Report any error we got.

        print("Error: \(error)")

        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()

        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"

        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError

        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)

        // TODO: Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and 
        // terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping 
        // application, although it may be useful during development.

        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")

        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()
```

to this:

```
catch let error as NSError {
        // Report any error we got.

        print("Error: \(error)")

        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()

        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"

        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError

        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)

        // TODO: Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and 
        // terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping 
        // application, although it may be useful during development.

        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")

        abort()
    }
    catch {
        // << ADDED THIS "CATCH-ALL" >>
        fatalError()
    }

    return coordinator
}()
```

...and surprisingly, the warning above ("cast always fails") is unwarranted and the code executes flawlessly...

**SERIOUSLY, APPLE?**

Comment: What happens if you wrote something like:
`var itemsA = items as! Array<Any>`
to see if casting helps?

Comment: It crashes on that same line with `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0` (on the simulator).

Comment: Set a breakpoint and examine `items` in the debugger. What is it?  My guess is NSArray

Comment: Close, `NSMutableArray`. Silly me I didn't try this earlier. What's the proper way to deal with a JSON using native Swift collection types?

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't notice the mutable containers option. Since you are testing the class you need to use the class that it actually *is*. NSMutableArray is a swift array in that you can use Swift array operations but when testing the type of a variable it isn't actually a swift array.

Comment: I can not cast it into an `Array` of a specific type (e.g., `Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>`), though. Seriously, the transition to Swift still has some rough edges...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already discovered, it returns an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionary`. To convert it to an array of dictionaries in Swift:

```
if var items = items as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    print(items[0])
} else {
    print("Really?")
}
```

This is the reason why I much prefer SwiftyJSON to `NSJSONSerializer`.

You probably see a lot fewer `if var` than `if let`. `if var` is used here to keep your array mutable, since you specified the `MutableContainers` option.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I don't need the mutable option but couldn't figure out  default argument to pass to `options:` (`nil` won't compile).

Comment: Use an empty set: `options: []`

Comment: I get the compiler warning `Cast from 'NSMutableArray' to unrelated type '[[String : AnyObject]]' always fails`.

Comment: Did you use it inside the `if` statement like in my answer? If not, you have to use a forced downcast `as!`

Comment: Yes, same `if` block. It _does_ work at runtime (???!!!!). See my updates for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
let itemsArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

itemsArray = dictionary["items"]

print(itemsArray)
```

Try like this..

Comment: I don't need to move from `NSMutableArray` to `NSArray`; I need a (native, non-Foundation) Swift `Array`.